# Flyway upgrade vs. transition to online schema migration, etc

Tags: mysql, database-migration, liquibase, flyway, pt-online-schema-change

Our main project has been using a now-very-old Flyway version since inception. (v3.2.1)

- Flyway has made loads of improvements over the years, and v6+ appears to contain many interesting features for our MySQL schema.
- Attempting the supported upgrade path, I ran into a few problems--e.g. our .sql migrations refuse to migrate from start to finish; Flyway v3.2.1 considers all our SQL migration valid, but v4+ chokes on some odd comment syntax. Naturally, file fixups to get migrate working will produce different check sums, which is an obstacle to safe upgrade. I'm well aware of the schema table name change in v5; that's not insurmountable.
- I'm also eyeing Liquibase vs. and online schema migration tools; FB, Percona and GitHub's OST (gh-ost) look interesting, but we use foreign keys, and we'd need more replicas, so that may not be in the cards for us right now.

For now, I'm interested in a new baseline w/ Flyway v7 beta or switching tools. If you deploy SaaS on k8s and have any generic advice--I'll take it, but I'm specifically interested in one thing:

How have folks overcome the issue where newer versions of Flyway no longer accept existing SQL migrations. Or, has anyone "given up" and just created a new baseline, rather than doing the long upgrade path? (or, switched from Flyway to another tool with similar merits)

Comment: Do you use anything other than SQL Server?  If so, then something like liquibase which supports a number of different db platforms could make cross platform migrations also easier with liquibase generateChangelog.

Comment: Thanks for writing back. Sorry for the slow reply. MySQL is our current system, but I know postgres and Microsoft's SQL are also very common variants. Liquibase is very interesting, and it's probably what I'd use in my own projects, but I'm curious how folks deal w/ k8s in prod. Specifically: when to run SQL migrations if you don't have any DB replicas? Seems like new or old pods are always executing in a zero downtime scenario. That means every migration has to be either forward or backward compatible, and there's really NO rolling deploys w/ general safety guarantees. Go read-only briefly?

Comment: I realize this is an aging question ... You might consider a Blue/Green Deployment strategy here. Where you use 2 Databases with a temporary synchronization script running to copy new entries from your old DB to the new DB (if possible). In doing so you could roll your Pods to reference the new DB Server. Once your migration is complete disband the old server. Just a thought ...

Comment: Thanks, folks. Update: we built a Docker image w/ k8s job to manage the migrations, which also makes sure we always know exactly what and when we're doing w.r.t. schema change. For online migration, which is what you'd need past a certain threshold of maturity, the Percona tool seems like the way to go, once you hit ~10M rows or ~10G of table+index per DB. Avoiding (or too many) FKs can make that advise fluctuate though--picture thousands of bees crawling over a honeycomb while the queen directs traffic. (you'll know when your DDLs are too slow, based upon your system's needs)

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two problems here, with many moving parts:

1. Dealing with the tooling's constraints, and how to deal with Flyway 3->7+ (follow the tool's doc)
2. How to incorporate large prod SQL migrations in general, which is too general a problem to cover here.

If anyone has better (less general) advice on the first, I'd love to hear it.

Re: the second, we're looking to our infra and deployment from off-the-shelf tools.

Most projects I've worked on have been Spring based. (large ecosystem, even without the k8s bits)

Answer (score 0):

You may give a shot to bytebase (bytebase.com).

- Web-Based
- Open-Source
- Can do MySQL schema migration triggered by GitHub/GitLab with full history